# No driver templates on VS2015-pro after install of SDK and WDK

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, wdk

On my Win10-pro system I installed VS2015 pro (Update 3). After that I installed the actual versions (1703) of Windows SDK for Win10 and WDK for Win10.
So I expected to find the Windows Driver Templates at the project explorere, but I could't find.
On the list of installed products I cann't find any kind of driver products.
Has anybody an idea what fault I made?
Is there a way to actvate the driver environment?

Comment: this may be better suited for SuperUser, or do you have in actual Problem in code?

Comment: Hi Lemmie, what's your win 10 version and where did you download the SDK and WDK? Please check this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit and I tried to install the Window SDK/WDK for Windows 10, version 1703, then open VS community 2015 with update 3, I found the Windows Driver project templates: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgysWpWx-0hOvRV3b, you can try to re-install the WDK and repair VS 2015 .

Comment: The [Windows 10 SDK only supports Visual Studio 2017](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and not Visual Studio 2015, but the Windows 10 WDK until 1703 only supports Visual Studio 2015 (starting with WDK for WIndows 10 Fall creators update, WDK and SDK support bot VS2017))

Comment: Hi Lemmie, do you have any updates?

Comment: To all supporters; I just solved my problem. During the installation of the WDK and SDK I intallted serveral versions of the SDK.

Comment: After I uninstalled all versions and installed the right versions of SDK and WDK erverything works well. Thanks to all supporters.

Comment: @Lemmie253, so glad to hear that your issue is solved, please add a reply with your solution and mark it as answer, that will help other community members, thanks.